# Where to find the documentation for frappe on the github repo?

Tags: github, repository, open-source, code-documentation, frappe

I'm on the frappe github [repo](https://github.com/frappe/frappe) and I need to find the folder that contains the documentation to contribute to it. A link to it would be super helpful .

Comment: [Contribution guide](https://github.com/frappe/frappe/blob/develop/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md). It will always be in the folder called `.github`

Comment: Unless it's named differently, I didn't see it on there. Thank you for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Frappe Framework docs are not present on GitHub repo.

They are maintained using a wiki app. You can edit the docs using the `Edit Page` link at the bottom of every page.

[image]